# Как работают out файлы?

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, компилятор

До недавнего времени пользовался `MSVС` в `IDE` и не особо парился о том, как собираются `exe` файлы. Сейчас работаю на линуксоиде и столкнулся с непониманием, почему `out` файл показывается в свойствах как *shared library*? Это же исполняемый файл программы как `exe` в Windows. `out` файл я получил в следствии компиляции cpp файла

```
alex@alex-Lenovo:~/Documents/AtomWS_1$ g++ Testcpp.cpp
alex@alex-Lenovo:~/Documents/AtomWS_1$ ls
a.out  Testcpp  Testcpp.cpp
```

1) Что же такое этот `out` файл?
2) Почему я могу запустить его только из терминала?
3) Как собрать `exe` через g++?
Везде пишут о установке `MinGW`, но разве это не упрощённый набор инструментов GCC под Windows?

Comment: В каких еще свойствах? А вообще что на windows, что на linux, exe и dll имеют один и тот же формат и различаются разве что порядком инициализации / точкой входа. `exe` это просто расширение файла. Можете переименовать свой `out`.

Comment: @VTT properties -> Type : shared library (application/x-sharedlib) в этих свойствах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) a.out - в линуксе - имя по умолчанию для бинарных выполнимых файлов типа [ELF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format). Почему он у Вас называется "shared library"? да просто shared library (это .so файлы) и обычный бинарный выполнимый файл практически ничем не отличаются.

2) Вы можете его запустить и с "проводника" (наутилус, немо или другие). Но дело в том, что он запуститься, обнаружит, что нет терминала (при попытке ввода/вывода) и закроется. Но никто не мешает написать так, что бы к примеру показывало окошко.

3) а вот это уже называется кросс-компиляция. И для этого обычно используют mingw. MinGW - это такой специальный gcc, который умеет генерировать exe файл. А вот где он будет запущен - под windows или linux - дело десятое.